# How to list com devices in Dos terminal?

Tags: windows, operating-system, usb, dos, device

How do I list com devices in terminal ? The idea is to list a virtual COM port number enumerated when a Serial to USB  converter is plugged in.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify a particular Windows OS, but the [`chgport`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771976.aspx) command may be useful if you have Vista or upwards.

It looks like this on my Windows 8 system:

[image: chgport]

Comment: Thank you. But does this not list Virtual com ports ?

Comment: The only 2 COM ports I have active are both virtual, and they show up: http://i.imgur.com/rXVS4cc.jpg The second issuing of the command was when they were in use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Microsoft makes a utility called "USBView" Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It might do what you are looking for.